# jqueryui Tabs + onunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jqueryui tabs on a page which, when clicking the "Tabs" links switches various `<section>` elements around my page, in other words, all my content is on one page (one file).

The problem I am having, is that on one `<section>` or one of the "Tabs" if you will, I want to make sure a user has filled out all fields / submitted a form before leaving that section. It is a multi-part multi ajax request form. Thus, if the user has filled out everything and submitted, that's ok. He can leave afterwards.

However, if the user begins the form submission, but doesn't complete, and tries to click on another tab, I want to have a popup like **"Stay on Page**, **"Leave Page"**.

In the dom, there is I believe a `onunload` hook that I can use, but I don't know how to do this in **jqueryui tabs**. Any ideas what hook I can use with the plugin?

**My jqueryui tabs code:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

My html structure:

**The navigation:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

**The Content:**

```
<div id="tabs" class="container">
  <section id="tabs-1">
    // Tabs 1 stuff goes here
  </secion>
  <section id="tabs-2">
    // Tabs 1 stuff goes here
  </secion>
  <section id="tabs-3">
    // Tabs 1 stuff goes here
  </secion>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this event http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate to achieve that.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        beforeActivate: function(e, ui){
            if ( ui.oldTab.attr('id') == 'tabs-1' ) {
                if (confirm('Sure you want to leave?')) { 
                    return false
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```